# Can I use Twitter Bootstrap on only a portion of my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to gradually move a large existing rails 4 app to Bootstrap.  Is there any way to just use bootstrap with only a certain layout and not others?  Or could I just use bootstrap within a certain body tag?  I'm trying to avoid pulling in bootstrap font styling, etc. on all existing views.

I am using the asset pipeline.  Here's how I'm using the Bootstrap css in my application.css.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import '*';
```

Comment: How are you including bootstrap now, are you using the asset pipeline? Need to see some code. The short answer is, yes, you can do that.

Comment: Yes, I am using the pipeline.  Edits made to original question.

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two layout files, **application.html.erb** and **admin.html.erb**. You would then simply create two different manifest files, **application.css.scss** and **admin.css.scss**. However, you should also create a separate CSS file for Bootstrap, **bootstrap_custom.css.scss**.

**bootstrap_custom.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

*Note: You don't want to use `@import` in your manifest files since it will need to recompile each time and thus slow down development. Instead, use `require` when possible!*

**application.css.scss**

```
//= require bootstrap_custom
//= require_tree .
```

**admin.css.scss**

```
//= require_tree .
```

Then, correspondingly in your layout files

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

**admin.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin" %>
```

So now, your application layout has bootstrap and admin layout doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap will only be invoked on classes it associates in its selectors on web pages it is called in.  You could make a call to load bootstrap on only the page you want it to apply to.

Comment: I guess I'm asking how to do that.  I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem, and once I install it and add the import statements in application.scss, I start getting Bootstrap font styling in the app.

Comment: This is where the simplicity of Rails causes a problem.  I believe you can add the bootstrap into the header of all associated files by downloading the bootstrap.min.css and placing it in the portion of the project CSS files you want to use it.